# how to uninitialize std::experimental::optional

Tags: c++

how to uninitialize std::experimental::optional?

```
  std::experimental::optional<std::string> name;

  name = std::string("hello"); //how to uninitialize name?

  if(name)
  {
    std::cout << "name is set" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "name is not set" << std::endl;
  }
```

how can I hit the else branch?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you want.  Do you want both the if and else blocks to be executed or do you want to "null" out `name` so only the else block runs?

Comment: I want to uninitialize name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
name = std::experimental::nullopt;
```

[link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/nullopt)

> std::experimental::nullopt is a constant of type std::experimental::nullopt_t that is used to indicate optional type with uninitialized state.